# How can code inside an Objective-C block reference the block object itself?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

`self` is merely a captured variable inside a block and doesn't reference the block itself, so how does a block reference itself without having an explicit captured variable for that purpose?

Answer (score 16):

```
__block void(^strawberryFields)();
strawberryFields = [^{ strawberryFields(); } copy];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),
               strawberryFields);
```

- you use the `__block` because the block will make a copy of the value of `strawberryFields` when the block is created which will be *before the assignment*.
- you also must `copy` the block prior to any other copy operation or else you'll end up with a block that references the on-stack original version.
- note that the above code *leaks the block*.  Somewhere, there needs to be a `release` of that block to balance the copy.

Comment: "Somewhere, there needs to be a release" why not right after the `dispatch_async`?

Comment: I think "Somewhere, there needs to be a release" means that strawberryFields needs to be set to nil at some point. Otherwise, it's "Strawberry fields forever..."

Comment: @AndrewRondeau This was written before ARC was really a thing. :)

Answer (score 5):

I found this pattern to work and stable for ARC (automatic reference counting), both in Debug and Release builds.

```
-(void) someMethod
{
    // declare a __block variable to use inside the block itself for its recursive phase.
    void __block (^myBlock_recurse)();

    // define the block
    void (^myBlock)() = ^{
        // ... do stuff ...
        myBlock_recurse(); // looks like calling another block, but not really.
    };

    // kickstart the block
    myBlock_recurse = myBlock; // initialize the alias
    myBlock(); // starts the block
}
```

Initially I tried just putting a `__block` modifier to `myBlock` and use that variable directly to recurse within the block's implementation. That works on the ARC Debug build but breaks with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the Release build. On the other hand removing the `__block` modifier raises a "variable not defined when captured by block" warning (and I was reluctant to run it and test).

Comment: PS: crashes are in iOS 5.0, not sure about Mac.

Comment: can you show an example of code that crashes when you just use `myBlock` but does not crash when you use this `myBlock_recurse` thing?

Comment: In ARC, this causes a retain cycle

Comment: @newacct Temporary retain cycle – just make sure you assign `nil` to `myBlock_recurse` after recursion is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this before and not 100% sure it's useful, if valid, but for example:

```
typedef void (^BasicBlock)(void);

__block BasicBlock testBlock;
testBlock  = ^{NSLog(@"Testing %p", &testBlock);};
testBlock();
```

You probably have declare the variable with __block to prevent self-retain cycle.

Comment: Code is decidedly odd, but more or less correct.  The reasoning, though, is incorrect.

Comment: Sure;  see my answer.   The code wasn't that odd, really, just that printing the address of an `__block` variable is typically surprising (in that there is an implied indirection).

Comment: Yes, the address means nothing indeed. And I wasn't aware that the block will make a copy of the value _before_ the assignment, so __block is necessary regardless of self retaining. Thank you for the comment. If you let me ask just one more thing, how does block actually deal with __block variable when writing to it? Does it make a reference to the original (and possibly in-stack) variable?

Comment: A `__block` variable is effectively a handle;  a pointer to where the data is actually held.   It starts on the stack.  When you do a Block_copy() (or -copy), it allocates a bit of memory on the heap to hold the variables value, copies it, then updates the pointer in the __block to no longer point to the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then if I copy a block, in which I change the value of a __block variable, then the change is not visible inside the original scope?

Answer (score 0):

The block needs some way to nil out its own reference. Typically it is done by storing the block in a property of the class.

Sometimes you can prefer to not use a property. Here is how you do it without a property:

```
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    __block id block = ^{

        if(weakSelf) {

            // .. do whatever

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
        }
        else {

            block = nil;
        }
    };

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
```

The key thing to keep in mind is that all code paths must lead to a block = nil. We do that here by calling the block every 5 seconds until weakSelf turns nil.

Comment: As of XCode 5.0 (currently in beta) this throws a warning. The warning is wrong -- hopefully Apple makes this warning smarter in the future.

Comment: It's not wrong. You *are* causing a retain cycle (even if you try to break it later, which I'm not sure is correct). The better solution is to not have a retain cycle in the first place, by having the block capture a weak reference to itself.

Comment: If you're skeptical I suggest testing the code in XCode. Setting block = nil removes the retaining reference in arc. You can test it be setting a breakpoint at block = nil and copying the pointer to block in the pasteboard. Let the program run for a while (seems to take 1-5 seconds), pause the program, and po the pointer. In this way you can easily tell the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in ARC, it's a little different -- `__block` object pointer variables are by default retained in ARC, unlike in MRC. Thus, it will cause a retain cycle. It is necessary for the block to capture a weak reference to itself (using `__weak`) in order to not have a retain cycle.

However, we still need a strong reference to the block somewhere. If there are no strong references, the block (which is on the heap since it's copied) will be deallocated. Thus, we need two variables, one strong and one weak, and inside the block use the weak one to reference itself:

```
__block __weak void(^weakBlock)();
void(^myBlock)();
weakBlock = myBlock = [^{ weakBlock(); } copy];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),
               myBlock);
```

Comment: What will happen if we don't give `copy`?

Comment: @trss: Some versions of the compiler might automatically insert a copy (so you might not see any difference), but this is not guaranteed. If a copy is not made, the problem is that `weakBlock` will point to the stack block. And even though we might later be using a copy of the block (heap block), inside the block, the code still refers to `weakBlock`, which points to the stack block, so it will execute the stack block and cause problems. That's why the block must be copied before assigning to `weakBlock`.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives a warning about assigning to a weak variable (weakBlock), and the warning is right: weakBlock is deallocated immediately.

Comment: @puzzl: The warning is not right. It is assigned to `myBlock` which is a strong reference. An assignment expression evaluates to the result of the right side, and that result is assigned to a strong reference. The compiler is incorrectly picky about the ordering of the assignment. The code is correct according to the standard, but I have changed it to get rid of the warning.